# Text link fills in form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am wanting to learn how to create a text link, which when clicked fills in certain information on a form I have above.

So in context, I have a donate form with the fields - amount/country/projects.
Below it I have a few links under a header 'Our most urgent appeals'. This could be something like Housing in Africa - £100.

When this link is clicked, it fills in information in the form so the amount is £100, the country is Africa, the project is housing. The form will not submit, it will just be filled in ready for the user to alter anything they may wish to.

I have searched around for this but cannot find a suitable answer to help me. Can anyone assist?

For basic-ness , my form could look like this:

```
<form target="paypal" id="general-donate" class="form-horizontal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" data-validate="parsley" >

<div class="control-group">
    <label for="amount" class="control-label">
        Donation Amount (&#163;)
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" name="amount" data-min="5" min="5" value="10.00" required>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label for="os0" class="control-label">
        Country
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Country">
        <select name="os0">
            <option value="Where Needed Most">Where Needed Most </option>
            <option value="Africa">Africa </option>
            <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh </option>
            <option value="Palestine/Gaza">Palestine/Gaza </option>
            <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan </option>
            <option value="UK">UK </option>
            <option value="Burma">Burma </option>
            <option value="Syria">Syria </option>
            <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia </option>
            <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka </option>
            <option value="Kashmir">Kashmir </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label for="os1" class="control-label">
        Projects
    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Projects">
        <select name="os1">
            <option value="Where Needed Most">Where Needed Most </option>
            <option value="Food">Food </option>
            <option value="Water">Water </option>
            <option value="Medicine">Medicine </option>
            <option value="Water Wells">Water Wells </option>
            <option value="Hospitals">Hospitals </option>
            <option value="Disabled Assistance">Disabled Assistance </option>
            <option value="Eid Gift">Eid Gift </option>
            <option value="Housing">Housing </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-actions">

<button type="submit" id="buynow" class="btn btn-danger">
    Donate via PayPal
</button>

</div>
</form>
```

and my link is simply text below it. Once clicked, the relevant information fills on the form. The form is basic, an amount text input and 2 dropdown options.

Comment: Where does the data come from? You have tagged as Ajax, have you tried any JavaScript (Ajax) code?

Comment: the data I am hoping can just be a javascript variable that I can alter for each link. I would rather not go server side and bring in external data from files just for easy purposes.. Ajax is wrong I believe, my bad! I have detagged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a form programatically you just have to set the `value` attributes of the relevant inputs:

```
var amount = document.getElementsByName('amount')[0],
    os0 = document.getElementsByName('os0')[0],
    os1 = document.getElementsByName('os1')[0];

function setForm(amountValue, os0Value, os1Value) {
  amount.value = amountValue;
  os0.value = os0Value;
  os1.value = os1Value;
}

var link = document.getElementById('set-form');
link.onclick = function (e) {
  setForm(100, 'Africa', 'Housing');
};
```

in your html:

```
<a href="#" id='set-form'>click</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

ok, it could be done with jquery:

Create the follow javascript function:

```
function fillFields(amount, country, project) {
  $('input[name="amount"]').val(amount);
  $('select[name="os0"]').val(country);
  $('select[name="os1"]').val(project);
}
```

Then the html for your button should be something like

```
<button onclick="fillFields('100', 'Africa', 'housing')">Housing in Africa - £100</button>
```

Comment: This works also! Loads of ways to do this.. All of which I didn't know until now. so thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

"When this link is clicked, it fills in information in the form so the amount is £100, the country is Africa, the project is housing. The form will not submit, it will just be filled in ready for the user to alter anything they may wish to."

This should work:

```
<a class="click-me" href="javascript:;">Click Me</a>

<script>
// <![CDATA[
(function ($) {
   $(function () {
      $('body').delegate('.click-me', 'click', function () {
         $('input[name="amount"]').val('100'); // Set amount to £100
         $('select[name="os0"]').val('Africa'); // Set country to Africa
         $('select[name="os1"]').val('Housing'); // Set needed most to Housing
      });
   });
})(jQuery);
// ]]>
</script>
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NzX8V/

This would be a more flexible way:
(jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RLtVR/ )

```
<a class="click-me" rel="100,Africa,Housing" href="javascript:;">Click Me</a>

<script>
// <![CDATA[
(function ($) {
   $(function () {
      $('body').delegate('.click-me', 'click', function () {
         var rel = $(this).attr('rel').split(','),
         amount = rel[0], country = rel[1], needed = rel[2];
         $('input[name="amount"]').val(amount); // Set amount
         $('select[name="os0"]').val(country); // Set country
         $('select[name="os1"]').val(needed); // Set needed most
      });
   });
})(jQuery);
// ]]>
</script>
```

You could make this easier to maintain and read if you used data-* attributes from HTML5 instead of the rel attribute, but since I wasn't sure about your doctype, I figured I'd play it safe. For instance, instead of making them comma-separated and splitting them, you could just have the attributes data-amount="100" data-country="Africa" data-needed="Housing" and then reference those with the .attr() method of jQuery.